# TTimer not firing

Tags: delphi, windows-7, timer, delphi-7

I'm having a strange problem. I have a TTimer on my main form that should trig 500 msec. after the form is created.

It works fine when I run it from IDE, but when I run it on other W7 PC's the main form is created, but the timer doesn't fire. (Some components are not updated) If I click a control, everything is updated and the timer fires and every thing is fine. If I move the form, every thing is updated but timers are not started. If I run it on PC with Delphi installed, it works fine. No problem.

Code in MyForm.OnCreate is executed fine. `Timer.Enabled := True` makes no change.

Any idea what causes this? I'm really stuck here.

Best regards.

Comment: Delphi timers are fired in idle time. Check Task Mansger for differences in processor utilisation between your IDE machine ad the other PCs

Comment: Don't make us guess what your code is. Show it.

Comment: Put another temporary timer that would report if the original timer is enabled or not, in a label caption or something .

Comment: Brian, you are on to something. PC is using apx. 50% CPU time until I click a control. Goes down to 0-1%. Thanks, got something to work on now.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's about this idleness. There's nothing special about Delphi timers. Delphi timers fire whenever the timer's utility window receives a WM_TIMER, it's not checked in OnIdle or something.

Comment: Sertac, Done that. No matter haw many timers I put on the form, they don't start. Automatically or by enabling them manually in my OnCreate event. They start if I e.i. click on a Combobox...

Comment: @Peter - If the same thing is happening when you run the executable outside the debugger, try attaching the debugger after you run it to find out what it's doing.

Comment: @Sertac WM_TIMER is an artificially synthesised message that only gets created when a message queue has been emptied. Just like WM_PAINT. Idle time would be a loose way to describe the moment when a message queue is emptied and indeed that's when the VCL fires its OnIdle event.

Comment: @David - Loosely.., I'd disagree on a definition that says low priority messages are fired on VCL's idle time. Anyway, I get the point, thanks.

Comment: @Sertac: Windows itself makes `WM_TIMER` messages low priority. Send/PostMessage don't even put them in the message queue if there are any higher priority messages there. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), second paragraph of `Remarks` section.

Comment: This sounds to me like you have an exception in FormCreate that is being hidden somehow. If the form is not initialised properly, odd things will happen.

Comment: @Ken - Sure. I didn't think/say otherwise. I objected to the assertion that timers are fired in idle time. That's like saying input messages are processed *near idle* time. That doesn't make any sense. That's incorrect. Timer messages have low priority. That's the way to put it.

Comment: Maybe there's a confusion here. *"The message won't be posted unless the message queue is empty"*, that's an implementation detail on part of the OS, the application won't see the queue empty; PeekMessage will retrieve the timer message. After that, PeakMessage may return either true or false depending on what the application is doing, and application *may* go idle.

Comment: @Sertac We're all saying the same thing. It's just that Brian's definition of idle time differs from yours. Credit to Brian, his comment hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @David, I guess you're right. Thanks one more time, for clearing me on this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of possibilities:

1. WM_TIMER messages are only delivered when your message queue is empty. If something in your app, or something in another app running on those other computers was posting messages to the window handle frequently enough that the message queue for that window never empties, WM_TIMER events would never fire.  If this was happening, you might have to wait 10x or 20x or 30x the normal TTimer period but the event would probably fire, eventually. I have not observed any situation so far gone that the timer doesn't fire at all, but that is of course, theoretically possible...
2. Although you say you know for sure that the timer is Enabled (you set it enabled) it is possible that somewhere ELSE in your code you're disabling it.
3. If you were doing some try...except..end blocks and ignoring an exception then something bad might be happening that you don't see on those other machines.
4. Your timer code might be firing, but an exception, crash or hang might be happening in the code that runs on the timer.
5. You might have, in your code, some series of Delphi event handlers which create a nearly "endless loop" situation because some event handlers you've written are firing when you don't want them to, causing side effects, which are keeping your application busy. You mention that you're clicking somewhere and the problem goes away.  That click might be enough to interrupt some other vicious cycle in your code.
6. You mention that it works on any PC with delphi installed on it. Are you using a third party control that has some limitations in it (like requiring that you run inside the debugger?). Or does your app load some DLLs or BPLs that are not installed on those other computers?

Start with a brand new application that has nothing in it. Add a TTimer.  Now on the timer event increment an integer field value and write that value to a caption of the form.  Now run it on the other machines.  It will work fine.

Now go look at the giant pile of code you wrote, and decide how to bisect your giant pile of code to find the half that is broken.  After enough steps, you will find your problem.  Nobody here can debug it for you.

Try adding some logging messages, using `OutputDebugString` and run DebugView on the other machines, if you want to see some internals of your application, on that other machine

Comment: 7. There might be some components on this form or in other forms which cause the main thread to overreact, thus not passing WM_TIMER (#1) message. Third party components (or built-in ones) can also do this. For example, a database connection like `TADOConnection` which is trying to connect to a database and is taking time.

Comment: @jerry threads don't overreact. You are anthropomorphising the Turing machine!

Comment: @Jerry. You were more or less spot on. I found the error yesterday. I set a TMS_PlannerDatepicker component to todays date at startup wich causes the CPU usage to go to 50%. I've done this many times, but in this application something goes wrong. I changed the component to the standard Delphi 7 DateTimePicker and everything works fine now.

Comment: I suspect that what Jerry calls "threads overreacting" is in fact a nearly endless cycle of cause-and-effect with messages being passed to controls (whether you see it or notice it or not) and events (callbacks) from those VCL controls causing more and more such events. This would lead to a chain of event handlers running that is more or less endless.  That an additional MOUSE_DOWN event or a change of active control could end such a loop speaks of Peter's code having a lot of mess in it to clean up. Perhaps some reentrancy guard flags are needed Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, however want to share with you this piece of gold, old but gold ;-)

You can also convert it to a thread (because timers are limited), I made an easy solution to this, an unit called `TimerAsThread`. Save the code as TimerAsThread.pas. You need to include this unit after extctrls or include it as last unit. You don't have to change your code, it works excactly the same however now based upon a thread. A thread is a separated process, search on google if you like more info.

Have fun.

```
{*******************************************************}
{                                                       }
{         Delphi VCL Extensions (RX)                    }
{                                                       }
{         Copyright (c) 1996 AO ROSNO                   }
{         Copyright (c) 1997, 1998 Master-Bank          }
{                                                       }
{*******************************************************}

unit TimerAsThread;

interface



uses {$IFDEF WIN32} Windows, {$ELSE} WinTypes, WinProcs, {$ENDIF}
  Messages, SysUtils, Classes;

type

{ TTimer }

  TTimer = class(TComponent)
  private
    FEnabled: Boolean;
    FInterval: Cardinal;
    FOnTimer: TNotifyEvent;
    FWindowHandle: HWND;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
    FSyncEvent: Boolean;
    FThreaded: Boolean;
    FTimerThread: TThread;
    FThreadPriority: TThreadPriority;
    procedure SetThreaded(Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetThreadPriority(Value: TThreadPriority);
{$ENDIF}
    procedure SetEnabled(Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetInterval(Value: Cardinal);
    procedure SetOnTimer(Value: TNotifyEvent);
    procedure UpdateTimer;
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  protected
    procedure Timer; dynamic;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
    procedure Synchronize(Method: TThreadMethod);
{$ENDIF}
  published
    property Enabled: Boolean read FEnabled write SetEnabled default True;
    property Interval: Cardinal read FInterval write SetInterval default 1000;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
    property SyncEvent: Boolean read FSyncEvent write FSyncEvent default True;
    property Threaded: Boolean read FThreaded write SetThreaded default True;
    property ThreadPriority: TThreadPriority read FThreadPriority write
      SetThreadPriority default tpNormal;
{$ENDIF}
    property OnTimer: TNotifyEvent read FOnTimer write SetOnTimer;
  end;

implementation

uses Forms, Consts, VCLUtils;

{$IFDEF WIN32}

{ TTimerThread }

type
  TTimerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FOwner: TTimer;
    FInterval: Cardinal;
    FException: Exception;
    procedure HandleException;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Timer: TTimer; Enabled: Boolean);
  end;

constructor TTimerThread.Create(Timer: TTimer; Enabled: Boolean);
begin
  FOwner := Timer;
  inherited Create(not Enabled);
  FInterval := 1000;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.HandleException;
begin
  if not (FException is EAbort) then begin
    if Assigned(Application.OnException) then
      Application.OnException(Self, FException)
    else
      Application.ShowException(FException);
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;

  function ThreadClosed: Boolean;
  begin
   if( Application.Terminated ) and ( NOT Terminated ) then
    Terminate;

   Result := Terminated or Application.Terminated or (FOwner = nil);
  end;

begin
  repeat
    if not ThreadClosed then
      if SleepEx(FInterval, False) = 0 then begin
        if not ThreadClosed and FOwner.FEnabled then
          with FOwner do
            if SyncEvent then Synchronize(Timer)
            else
              try
                Timer;
              except
                on E: Exception do begin
                  FException := E;
                  HandleException;
                end;
              end;
      end;
  until Terminated;
end;

{$ENDIF}

{ TTimer }

constructor TTimer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FEnabled := True;
  FInterval := 1000;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  FSyncEvent := True;
  FThreaded := True;
  FThreadPriority := tpNormal;
  FTimerThread := TTimerThread.Create(Self, False);
{$ELSE}
  FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
{$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TTimer.Destroy;
begin
  Destroying;
  FEnabled := False;
  FOnTimer := nil;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  {TTimerThread(FTimerThread).FOwner := nil;}
//  while FTimerThread.Suspended do FTimerThread.Resume;
  FTimerThread.Terminate;
  {if not SyncEvent then FTimerThread.WaitFor;}
  if FWindowHandle <> 0 then begin
{$ENDIF}
    KillTimer(FWindowHandle, 1);
    DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle);
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  end;
{$ENDIF}
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TTimer.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  with Msg do
    if Msg = WM_TIMER then
      try
        Timer;
      except
        Application.HandleException(Self);
      end
    else Result := DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TTimer.UpdateTimer;
begin
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  if FThreaded then begin
    if FWindowHandle <> 0 then begin
      KillTimer(FWindowHandle, 1);
      DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle);
      FWindowHandle := 0;
    end;
    if not FTimerThread.Suspended then FTimerThread.Suspend;
    TTimerThread(FTimerThread).FInterval := FInterval;
    if (FInterval <> 0) and FEnabled and Assigned(FOnTimer) then begin
      FTimerThread.Priority := FThreadPriority;
      while FTimerThread.Suspended do FTimerThread.Resume;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if not FTimerThread.Suspended then FTimerThread.Suspend;
    if FWindowHandle = 0 then FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WndProc)
    else KillTimer(FWindowHandle, 1);
    if (FInterval <> 0) and FEnabled and Assigned(FOnTimer) then
      if SetTimer(FWindowHandle, 1, FInterval, nil) = 0 then
        raise EOutOfResources.Create(ResStr(SNoTimers));
  end;
{$ELSE}
  KillTimer(FWindowHandle, 1);
  if (FInterval <> 0) and FEnabled and Assigned(FOnTimer) then
    if SetTimer(FWindowHandle, 1, FInterval, nil) = 0 then
      raise EOutOfResources.Create(ResStr(SNoTimers));
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TTimer.SetEnabled(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FEnabled then begin
    FEnabled := Value;
    UpdateTimer;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimer.SetInterval(Value: Cardinal);
begin
  if Value <> FInterval then begin
    FInterval := Value;
    UpdateTimer;
  end;
end;

{$IFDEF WIN32}

procedure TTimer.SetThreaded(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FThreaded then begin
    FThreaded := Value;
    UpdateTimer;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimer.SetThreadPriority(Value: TThreadPriority);
begin
  if Value <> FThreadPriority then begin
    FThreadPriority := Value;
    if FThreaded then UpdateTimer;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimer.Synchronize(Method: TThreadMethod);
begin
  if (FTimerThread <> nil) then begin
    with TTimerThread(FTimerThread) do begin
      if Suspended or Terminated then Method
      else TTimerThread(FTimerThread).Synchronize(Method);
    end;
  end
  else Method;
end;

{$ENDIF}

procedure TTimer.SetOnTimer(Value: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTimer) <> Assigned(Value) then begin
    FOnTimer := Value;
    UpdateTimer;
  end else FOnTimer := Value;
end;

procedure TTimer.Timer;
begin
  if FEnabled and not (csDestroying in ComponentState) and
    Assigned(FOnTimer) then FOnTimer(Self);
end;

end.
```

Comment: *"because timers are limited"* - There's no such thing. Actually it can be argued that threads are more limited. With the default stack size, a 32 bit process can be expected to start about 2000 threads. Timers are user objects, which default to 10000 per process.